# Reload `filebacked.big.matrix` with R session crash

Tags: r, matrix, r-bigmemory

Thanks for reading this post!

Here I have an problem using big.matrix in R.With the code below:

```
big_matrix_object=as.big.matrix(matrix_object,backingfile='back.bin',descriptorfile='back.desc,backingpath='./path/)
```

if I save the `big_matrix_object` into the `.RData`.And the next time when I reload it the R session will encounter an crash.How can I avoid that?Appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your big_matrix_object in R is a pointer to the backing file stored on the disk; it must be re-attached to the file each time after restarting an R session, even if the previous session's .RDATA file has been loaded. Fortunately an easy fix—after restarting R and reloading the bigmemory package, run:

```
big_matrix_object <- attach.big.matrix("./path/back.desc")
```

This of course presumes the big.matrix object, and its associated backing file, were successfully created and saved in the prior session.

Cheers!

Comment: Thank you for the answer,@Jeff What you mean is that I should attach the matrix every time when I start the R session.So when I am trying to save the objects into the .RDATA ,I should somehow exclude the big.matrix objects which seems not an very elegant solution.Do you have any other way to handle it?I do find another package `bigmemoryExtra` which seems like the enhancement of the original `bigmemroy` but every time when I reload the .RDATA the big.matrix objects are not complete anymore though without session crash.

Comment: You're welcome; glad to help. A big.matrix consists of an object in R that does nothing more than point to the data structure that, in your case, is stored on disk. That is the whole point of the file backed big matrix; it allows you create and manipulate data structures too large to be stored in memory (and thus is not actually ever loaded into the R workspace). You don't need to exclude anything when you save your workspace/data. I urge you to read this document explaining how bigmemory manages data (particularly page 6): [BM](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/bigmemory/bigmemory.pdf)